# ASP.NET - How to reference a LinkButton within ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, listview, dataset

I've created a `ListView` with a dataset and I'm wondering how to reference to a `LinkButton` within a `ListView`, since I can't reach it in code behind.

The `LinkButton` is within `ItemTemplate`. I need to have it in code behind since I'm calling a if function on it. I've also tried OnClientClick on the linkbutton, but can't reach that either.

I'm sure I'm not the only one doing this, so is there another way to do this? more efficient?

Simplified code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstVDataBind" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btndeleteClick" runat="server"><span>X</span></asp:LinkButton>                        
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
btndeleteClick.Text = "for example"
```

But I can't reach it in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<asp:LinkButton Id="Linkbtn" CommandName="Linkbutn" runat="server"/>
```

then in code behind,

```
protected void lstVDataBind_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     (e.CommandName == "Linkbutn")
    {
         //do somthing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just had to add this into my ListView properties: `OnItemCommand="lstVDataBind_ItemCommand"`